# Refresh the GUI from DataSource in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have an object `MyPerson` with the properties `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `FullName` where

```
public string FullName
{
    get {return LastName + " " + FirstName;}
    set {...}
}
```

I bind the MyPerson to a `UserControl`, in which I bind FirstName, LastName and FullNAme to 3 texboxes.

Now, when I modify the FirstName or LastName I need to indicate to the UserControl to "update" the FullName.

What should be this "update" command?

Silverlight 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably look in to the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface. This will make your life MUCH easier.

---

Example:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
  }

  private String _FirstName;
  private String _LastName;

  public String FirstName
  {
    get
    {
      return this._FirstName;
    }
    set
    {
      if (this._FirstName != value)
      {
        this._FirstName = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FullName");
      }
    }
  }

  public String LastName
  {
    get
    {
      return this._LastName;
    }
    set
    {
      if (this._LastName != value)
      {
        this._LastName = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FullName");
      }
    }
  }

  public String FullName
  {
    get
    {
      return String.Format("{0} {1}", this.LastName, this.FirstName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement it. Notify FirstName, notify LastName... but this does not seem to wrok

Comment: Now I see that I should Notify not just the modified property, but also the dependent properties.... This is a little embarassing...if we don't know a priori all the dependent properties... but this is a solution however...

Comment: @serhio: Keep in mind it's all event driven. In the background it's seeing if `obj` is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If so, it binds to the event and looks for which properties it should be notified of updates on. If you don't tell it that the partial name (and by proxy the full name) have been updated, it won't be aware, and thus won't update. ;-)

Comment: @Brad Christie: Can I tell to the "background" to update all the public properties of the object? like `NotifyProperty("*")` (all)?

Comment: The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

Answer (score 1):

Your view model should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) Interface, so it can notify the view of the changed properties.

Look here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx

Also, if any of first or last name changes, you'd need to notify of a change in fullname, too.